# Projection with same rank

Tags: functional-analysis, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and $P$, $Q$ are two projections over $H$ such that $\|P-Q\|<1$. I am searching for a simple proof for
$$
\dim\operatorname{Ran}P=\dim\operatorname{Ran}Q,\quad \dim\operatorname{Ran}(I-P)=\dim\operatorname{Ran}(I-Q).
$$

To handle with this, we can define $R=(P-Q)^2$ and $U_1=QP+(I-Q)(I-P)$, $V_1=PQ+(I-P)(I-Q)$. Then it is easy to verify that
$$
U_1V_1=V_1U_1=I-R,\quad U_1^*=V_1,\quad V_1^*=U_1.
$$
Since $\|R\|<1$, $T=(I-R)^{-\frac12}$ makes sense (e.g. define it with series) and it commutes with $P$, $Q$. Set
$$
U=U_1T,\quad V=V_1T,
$$
then $UV=VU=I$ and
$$
Q=UPU^{-1},\quad P=VQV^{-1}.
$$
but this proof is too long and complicated, compared with the given condition. Therefore, I want to find an intuitive way to show that.

Comment: I met this problem when discussing discrete spectrum of self-adjoint operator with perturbation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assumption implies that $P$ is injective on ${\rm Ran}\,Q.$ Indeed assume that $Pv=0,$ $Qv=v\neq 0.$ Then $$\|v\|=\|Pv-Qv\|<\|v\|$$ a contradiction. As   $P({\rm Ran}\,Q)\subset {\rm Ran}\,P$ we get $\dim {\rm Ran}\,P\ge   \dim {\rm Ran}\,Q.$ By symmetry we get the converse inequality.

The same conclusion holds for $P'=I-P$ and $Q'=I-Q,$ as $\|P'-Q'\|<1.$

Since the ranks are equal there is an invertible operator $U$ such that $U({\rm Ran}\,P)={\rm Ran}\,Q$ and $ U({\rm Ran}\,(I-P))=\rm Ran(I-Q).$ We get $P=U^{-1}QU.$ The operator $U$ is unitary if $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal projections.

Comment: It is not generally true that $P(\text{ran}(Q)) = \operatorname{ran}(Q)$. Did you mean to say that their dimensions are the same? Or perhaps $P(\text{ran}(Q)) = \operatorname{ran}(P)$?

Comment: As a quick example, consider
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad Q = \frac 12\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$
we find that $\|P - Q\| = 1/\sqrt{2} < 1$.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I meant that $P$ is  an isomorphism from the range of $Q$ onto the range of $P.$ But actually the inclusion suffices

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am not sure that if $P$ is an injection from range of $Q$ to range of $P$, then it must be $\dim\operatorname{P}\leq\dim\operatorname{Q}$? Since there exists injection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $A$ is an injection from $V$ to $W,$ then $\dim W\ge \dim V.$ I have never seen a linear injection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by contrapositive.

Suppose $\dim \operatorname{ran}(P) \neq \dim \operatorname{ran}(Q)$. Without loss of generality, suppose $\dim \operatorname{ran}(P) > \dim \operatorname{ran}(Q)$. As a consequence (as I prove below), we can deduce that $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(P) \cap \operatorname{ran}(Q)^\perp) > 0$, so that there exists a non-zero vector $x \in \operatorname{ran}(P) \cap \operatorname{ran}(Q)^\perp$. From there, it suffices to note that $\operatorname{ran}(Q)^\perp = \ker(Q)$, so that
$$
\|(P - Q)x\| = \|Px - Qx\| = \|x - 0\| = \|x\|,
$$
so that $\|P - Q\| \geq 1$.

Thus, $\dim \operatorname{ran}(P) \neq \dim \operatorname{ran}(Q)$ implies that $\|P - Q\| \geq 1$. Similarly, $\dim\operatorname{ran}(I - P) \neq \dim \operatorname{ran}(I - Q)$ implies that $\|(I - P) - (I - Q)\| = \|P - Q\| \geq 1$. The conclusion follows.

---

> **Claim:** For closed subspaces $U,V \subset H$, $\dim(U) > \dim(V)$ implies that $\dim(U \cap V^\perp) > 0$.

*Proof:* Consider the quotient space $Q = H/V^\perp$, noting that $\dim(Q) = \dim(V)$. Let $\pi: H \to Q$ denote the associated projection map. Now, consider the restriction $\phi = \pi|_U:U \to Q$. Note that
$$
\dim \operatorname{ran}(\phi) \leq \dim Q = \dim V.
$$
Note that $\ker\phi = U \cap V^\perp$. On the other hand, $\phi$ induces an injective map $\tilde \phi:U/\ker\phi \to Q$, with $\operatorname{ran}(\tilde\phi) = \operatorname{ran}\phi$. Thus, we have
$$
\dim (U/\ker \phi) = \dim(\text{ran}(\phi)) \leq \dim V \implies\\
\dim(U) \leq \dim(V) + \dim \ker \phi.
$$
Because $\dim(V) < \dim(U)$, we are forced to conclude that $\dim \ker \phi = \dim (U \cap V^\perp)$ is positive, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks! But there seem to be two typos: an extra equal sign '$=$' in your main proof, and  $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(\phi))\leq\dim V$ instead of $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(\phi))\leq\dim U$. Despite some minor typos, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Maka Thanks for catching the errors. And you're welcome!